(xAct) AllContractions with sum of terms
I'm doing some GR calculations using xAct package. In order to find all dimensional-dependent-identities (DDIs), mathematica has to apply the AllContraction method from xTras. Here is my input
AllContractions[
 epsilong[n, o, p, q] epsilong[-a, -b, -c, -d] RiemannCD[e, k, l, 
   m] RiemannCD[-r, -s, -u, -v], {-a, -b}]

where epsilong is the Levi-Civita tensor associated to my metric tensor g.
I get two errors:

ToCanonical::noident "Unknown expression not canonicalized: VerbatimPlus(...
AllContractions:Number of indices and range of symmetry doesn't match.

However, when one removes one of the epsilong, this works fine !
Can you help me ?
EDIT:
The mistake comes from the fact that the function AllContractions uses the function SymmetryOf, that cannot be applied on a sum of terms (apparently. That's why it works when one removes one of the epsilong. Any idea to solve this issue?
TrodaroX
